# How to translate "Premium Canadian casual wear"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, québec, france

It would be used on a badge stitch on t-shirts, in both English and French. I would like a common (no weird phrases) and modern translation, not too verbose, but able to translate the English meaning clearly and precisely.

Would love a translation which is also idiomatic in Quebec French? Is there a difference?

Google translate has:

> Vêtements décontractés canadiens haut de gamme.

Comment: Je ne fermerais pas la question ; elle a été modifiée ; il y a 3 adjectifs à relier à un nom, la question est un peu de savoir comment on enfile ça... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The question suggested the following. I'm adding it as a community wiki so people can vote on it if they find it useful:

> [*Vêtements décontractés canadiens haut de gamme.*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/51828/26366) [Google translate]

Answer (score 0):

The following translations would be understood in Quebec, but may not be the preferred  ones.

- habillement de ville canadien (de) premier choix
- vêtements de ville canadiens (de) premier choix
- tenues de ville canadiennes de première qualité

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I leave my original answer here; maybe it can be useful.

You should edit your question and provide additional details. As it is currently, it risks to be closed. What have you tried? What is your particular issue? FSE is not a translation application per se. For instance, you could have asked what is the proper way to convey 'casual wear'.

1. Google translate
   https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr&sl=en&tl=fr&text=casual%20wear&op=translate

> Casual wear =  vêtements de tous les jours

2. Linguee
   https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/casual+wear.html

> Casual wear  = tenue décontractée

3. Deepl
   https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/casual%20wear

> Casual wear =  vêtements de loisirs ; tenue décontractée
> vêtements décontractés ; tenue de loisirs

---

**EDIT 2** After taking into @jlliagre's comment.

My two cents for your turn:

*Vêtements canadiens décontractés de haut de gamme*

Comment: @viande-à-chien Merci ! J'ai fait la modification.

Comment: @viande can you view my post again is the google translation good?

Comment: @ccs Thanks. What de?

Comment: @Dimitris *Pour **d**'occasions **non-[formelles](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1999)*** is weird.